# How to properly group data by distinct employee

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables of data, one is a transactional table that links each employee to software usage across the Fiscal Year 2020, the other is the table of employees. They have a Primary Key relationship called trackingid. Therefore, for one employee they could have many transactions. We also calculate usage hours of the software and we want to sum that as number of days of use.

My goal is to generate a report that shows the Distinct User, plus the other columns plus Calculated Usage Days grouped properly. Each time I am trying to get the selection to work, I am getting 1 row of each instance of software use by hours.

Since I am not very good at SQL I am struggling with the GROUP BY and AGGREGATE functions I need to properly generate this output.

```
select DISTINCT w.[TrackingId], w.[FirstName], w.[LastName], w.[Email], w.UserName, 
w.[OfficeAddress1], w.[OfficeCity],w.[OfficeCountry], w.[OfficePostCode], w.[SupervisorName],w.[Department], w.[DepartmentName],w.[Organization], t.ProductName, t.FiscalPeriod, t.UsageHours
from 
 dbo.Employee_Users w INNER JOIN
 dbo.SoftwareTransactions t ON w.TrackingID = t.TrackingId
```

Example Data Looks like this:

```
FirstName,LastName,Email,UserName,OfficeAddress1,OfficeCity,OfficeCountry,OfficePostCode,SupervisorName,Department,DepartmentName,Organization,ProductName,FiscalPeriod,UsageHours
Employee1,Employee1LN,Employee1.Employee1LN@Company.com,Employee1LNA,Siemensstr 10,Neu-Isenburg,Germany,63263,"Supervisor1",A224,522.DEU EMIA MGMT Ops IT,52.Company GMBH.EUDEU1.A224,ARC/INFO,FY2020-Q1-10,0.107
Employee1,Employee1LN,Employee1.Employee1LN@Company.com,Employee1LNA,Siemensstr 10,Neu-Isenburg,Germany,63263,"Supervisor1",A224,522.DEU EMIA MGMT Ops IT,52.Company GMBH.EUDEU1.A224,ARC/INFO,FY2020-Q1-12,0.316
Employee1,Employee1LN,Employee1.Employee1LN@Company.com,Employee1LNA,Siemensstr 10,Neu-Isenburg,Germany,63263,"Supervisor1",A224,522.DEU EMIA MGMT Ops IT,52.Company GMBH.EUDEU1.A224,ARC/INFO,FY2020-Q1-12,1.627
Employee1,Employee1LN,Employee1.Employee1LN@Company.com,Employee1LNA,Siemensstr 10,Neu-Isenburg,Germany,63263,"Supervisor1",A224,522.DEU EMIA MGMT Ops IT,52.Company GMBH.EUDEU1.A224,ARC/INFO,FY2020-Q2-01,0.027
Employee1,Employee1LN,Employee1.Employee1LN@Company.com,Employee1LNA,Siemensstr 10,Neu-Isenburg,Germany,63263,"Supervisor1",A224,522.DEU EMIA MGMT Ops IT,52.Company GMBH.EUDEU1.A224,ARC/INFO,FY2020-Q2-01,1.21
Employee1,Employee1LN,Employee1.Employee1LN@Company.com,Employee1LNA,Siemensstr 10,Neu-Isenburg,Germany,63263,"Supervisor1",A224,522.DEU EMIA MGMT Ops IT,52.Company GMBH.EUDEU1.A224,ARC/INFO,FY2020-Q2-01,4.548
Employee1,Employee1LN,Employee1.Employee1LN@Company.com,Employee1LNA,Siemensstr 10,Neu-Isenburg,Germany,63263,"Supervisor1",A224,522.DEU EMIA MGMT Ops IT,52.Company GMBH.EUDEU1.A224,ARC/INFO,FY2020-Q2-02,0.02
Employee1,Employee1LN,Employee1.Employee1LN@Company.com,Employee1LNA,Siemensstr 10,Neu-Isenburg,Germany,63263,"Supervisor1",A224,522.DEU EMIA MGMT Ops IT,52.Company GMBH.EUDEU1.A224,ARC/INFO,FY2020-Q2-02,0.911
Employee1,Employee1LN,Employee1.Employee1LN@Company.com,Employee1LNA,Siemensstr 10,Neu-Isenburg,Germany,63263,"Supervisor1",A224,522.DEU EMIA MGMT Ops IT,52.Company GMBH.EUDEU1.A224,ARC/INFO,FY2020-Q2-03,7.022
Employee1,Employee1LN,Employee1.Employee1LN@Company.com,Employee1LNA,Siemensstr 10,Neu-Isenburg,Germany,63263,"Supervisor1",A224,522.DEU EMIA MGMT Ops IT,52.Company GMBH.EUDEU1.A224,ARC/INFO,FY2020-Q2-03,104.896
Employee1,Employee1LN,Employee1.Employee1LN@Company.com,Employee1LNA,Siemensstr 10,Neu-Isenburg,Germany,63263,"Supervisor1",A224,522.DEU EMIA MGMT Ops IT,52.Company GMBH.EUDEU1.A224,ARC/INFO,FY2020-Q2-03,148.505
Employee1,Employee1LN,Employee1.Employee1LN@Company.com,Employee1LNA,Siemensstr 10,Neu-Isenburg,Germany,63263,"Supervisor1",A224,522.DEU EMIA MGMT Ops IT,52.Company GMBH.EUDEU1.A224,ARC/INFO,FY2020-Q3-04,719.469
Employee1,Employee1LN,Employee1.Employee1LN@Company.com,Employee1LNA,Siemensstr 10,Neu-Isenburg,Germany,63263,"Supervisor1",A224,522.DEU EMIA MGMT Ops IT,52.Company GMBH.EUDEU1.A224,ARC/INFO,FY2020-Q3-06,2260.458
Employee1,Employee1LN,Employee1.Employee1LN@Company.com,Employee1LNA,Siemensstr 10,Neu-Isenburg,Germany,63263,"Supervisor1",A224,522.DEU EMIA MGMT Ops IT,52.Company GMBH.EUDEU1.A224,ARC/INFO,FY2020-Q4-07,616.381
Employee1,Employee1LN,Employee1.Employee1LN@Company.com,Employee1LNA,Siemensstr 10,Neu-Isenburg,Germany,63263,"Supervisor1",A224,522.DEU EMIA MGMT Ops IT,52.Company GMBH.EUDEU1.A224,ARC/INFO,FY2020-Q4-09,1846.506
Employee1,Employee1LN,Employee1.Employee1LN@Company.com,Employee1LNA,Siemensstr 10,Neu-Isenburg,Germany,63263,"Supervisor1",A224,522.DEU EMIA MGMT Ops IT,52.Company GMBH.EUDEU1.A224,ARC/INFO,FY2020-Q4-09,2489.788
Employee1,Employee1LN,Employee1.Employee1LN@Company.com,Employee1LNA,Siemensstr 10,Neu-Isenburg,Germany,63263,"Supervisor1",A224,522.DEU EMIA MGMT Ops IT,52.Company GMBH.EUDEU1.A224,Viewer,FY2020-Q1-10,1.792
```

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data, and the result you're trying to get for this sample

Comment: ok due to GDPR I am limited on what I can share. Let me clean it up and then share it.

Comment: It doesn't need to be real data - even some fake data with made up employees and transactions can help illustrate what you're trying to do

Comment: I added some fake data for one user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT DISTINCT in practice is just a simpler way of doing a specific type of GROUP BY - where you GROUP BY each field.

For example,

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c
FROM mytable;
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM mytable
GROUP BY a, b, c
```

However, if you *don't* want to group by all the fields, you need to use the GROUP BY clause.

The way I do these is to start with what we expect to be on one row (and GROUP BY these). In your case, I guess that it would be a user's product per fiscal year.

Therefore I would start with all the relevant rows that we want to GROUP BY on (note - this is all but the last field)

```
select 
    w.[TrackingId], 
    w.[FirstName], 
    w.[LastName], 
    w.[Email], 
    w.UserName, 
    w.[OfficeAddress1], 
    w.[OfficeCity],
    w.[OfficeCountry], 
    w.[OfficePostCode], 
    w.[SupervisorName],
    w.[Department], 
    w.[DepartmentName],
    w.[Organization], 
    t.ProductName, 
    t.FiscalPeriod
from 
    dbo.Employee_Users w 
    INNER JOIN dbo.SoftwareTransactions t ON w.TrackingID = t.TrackingId
group by
    w.[TrackingId], 
    w.[FirstName], 
    w.[LastName], 
    w.[Email], 
    w.UserName, 
    w.[OfficeAddress1], 
    w.[OfficeCity],
    w.[OfficeCountry], 
    w.[OfficePostCode], 
    w.[SupervisorName],
    w.[Department], 
    w.[DepartmentName],
    w.[Organization], 
    t.ProductName, 
    t.FiscalPeriod;
```

The above should give you the correct number of rows.

Following on from that, add the 'aggregate' values - these are the ones that take multiple rows and summarise into one.

In your case, I guess you want the SUM of hours (to get the total hours).

So the final answer would be

```
select 
    w.[TrackingId], 
    w.[FirstName], 
    w.[LastName], 
    w.[Email], 
    w.UserName, 
    w.[OfficeAddress1], 
    w.[OfficeCity],
    w.[OfficeCountry], 
    w.[OfficePostCode], 
    w.[SupervisorName],
    w.[Department], 
    w.[DepartmentName],
    w.[Organization], 
    t.ProductName, 
    t.FiscalPeriod,
    SUM(t.UsageHours) as TotalUsageHours    /* this is the only row added */
from 
    dbo.Employee_Users w 
    INNER JOIN dbo.SoftwareTransactions t ON w.TrackingID = t.TrackingId
group by
    w.[TrackingId], 
    w.[FirstName], 
    w.[LastName], 
    w.[Email], 
    w.UserName, 
    w.[OfficeAddress1], 
    w.[OfficeCity],
    w.[OfficeCountry], 
    w.[OfficePostCode], 
    w.[SupervisorName],
    w.[Department], 
    w.[DepartmentName],
    w.[Organization], 
    t.ProductName, 
    t.FiscalPeriod;
```

Comment: This is close, the number of records went from 43536 to 7,382, but I know we don't have 7,382 users. I think the productname and fiscalperiod are part of the issue, I need them to distinguish my time period and core product in my where clause, but they are still showing many records per user. I want this rolled up to an individual, with sum of hours? Does this make sense?

Comment: I think I figured this out. I had to change my where clause.